# Postgresql - how to select the inserted row in the last 15min automatically

Tags: sql, postgresql

i'm working on a table where new rows inserted everyday and we have a column where we persist the date/time for each new row.

```
ID      creation_date
56547   20/07/2021 11:47
56546   20/07/2021 11:47
56545   20/07/2021 11:47
56544   20/07/2021 11:45
56543   20/07/2021 11:45
56542   20/07/2021 11:44
56541   20/07/2021 11:44
56540   20/07/2021 11:43
56539   20/07/2021 11:42
56538   20/07/2021 11:42
56536   20/07/2021 11:41
56537   20/07/2021 11:41
56535   20/07/2021 11:41
...
```

i want to select the rows instered in the last 15min (sysdate-15). i'm new to postgresql i found that there is the function `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` but this function return the date+time zone
but in my column i have only HH:mm and i don't know how to add the -15min to the function..

do you have any idea how i can achieve this query ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the type of your column with the date?

Comment: @Tarik thank you for your time. the type is :  pg_typeof = "timestamp without time zone"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `now()` and subtract a 15 minute `interval`:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE creation_date >= now() - interval '15 minutes';
```

Demo:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id int, creation_date timestamp without time zone);
INSERT INTO t VALUES 
(1,now()-interval'1 hour'),
(2,now()-interval'5 minutes');

SELECT * FROM t
WHERE creation_date >= NOW() - interval '15 minutes';

 id |       creation_date       
----+---------------------------
  2 | 2021-07-22 12:41:02.60023
(1 row)
```